# Connection between pointed topological spaces and pointed categories

Tags: category-theory

Is there any motivation behind the name "pointed category" other than the fact that the category of pointed topological spaces is an obvious example of a pointed category?

Thank you.

Comment: You can think about pointed objects in any category with a terminal object. Every pointed category is equivalent to the category of pointed objects in some category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article
[initial and terminal objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) states

> If an object is both initial and terminal, it is called a
> **zero object** or **null object**. A **pointed category**
> is one with a zero object.

It later gives examples such as

> In the category of pointed sets (whose objects are non-empty sets together with a distinguished element; a morphism from $(A, a)$ to $(B, b)$ being a function
> $f : A \to B$ with $f(a) = b)$, every singleton is a zero object. Similarly, in the category of pointed topological spaces, every singleton is a zero object.

Notice that **Set**, the category of sets is not a pointed
category since, as the article states, there are no zero
objects.

The Wikipedia article
[Pointed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_space)
is about pointed topological spaces. It states

> The pointed set concept is less important; it is anyway the case of a pointed discrete space.

and thus, pointed sets can be regarded as a special case
of pointed spaces. The article also states

> Maps of pointed spaces (**based maps**) are continuous maps preserving basepoints, i.e., a map $f$ between a
> pointed space $X$ with basepoint $x_0$ and a pointed
> space $Y$ with basepoint $y_0$ is a based map if it is
> continuous with respect to the topologies of $X$ and
> $Y$ and if $f(x_0)=y_0.$ This is usually denoted
> $$f:(X,x_0) \to (Y,y_0). $$

You asked

> Is there any motivation behind the name "pointed category" other than the fact that the category of pointed topological spaces is an obvious example of a pointed category?

It seems that the simplest example of a pointed category
is the category of pointed sets where every singleton is
a zero object.
Next simplest example is the category of pointed spaces
where any one point space is a zero object.
Given the two examples of "points", it seems natural to
use "pointed" as an adjective for any of the many other
well-known categories which have zero objects.